# Appending list toggle (jQuery Mobile) not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

When I try to append a slider button using jQuery, it doesn't render properly.  Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v955K/.  If I use the same code and place it in the html file it works fine however.  Is append not the right method to use here?

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="review-note" data-title="Review Note">
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("<select name=\"slider\" id=\"flipMe\" data-role=\"slider\"><option value=\"off\">Off</option><option value=\"on\">On</option></select>").appendTo($("#content"));
```

Comment: have you tried using chrome, firefox or internet explorer's developer tools to see what is actually being injected and to where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`.slider()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/) at the end of your code to enhance markup of the switch button.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8TGJv/)**